# how to convert space to underscore in python list

Tags: python, list, replace

I have a list like this `['BASE',  'BASE xBU xPY',  'BU GROUP REL',  'PY REL']` and I want to convert it to `['BASE',  'BASE_xBU_xPY',  'BU_GROU_ REL',  'PY_REL']` in short convert space to underscore for value in b/w quotes

Comment: Okay, so what prevents you from doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using `replace` along with `map`

Example:

```
my_list = ['BASE', 'BASE xBU xPY', 'BU GROUP REL', 'PY REL']
converter = lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_')
my_list = list(map(converter, my_list))
my_list
```

```
['BASE', 'BASE_xBU_xPY', 'BU_GROUP_REL', 'PY_REL']
```